# Cannot ready property Calls of undefined

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, gulp-jest

In the above code block dispatcher is required and after register the mock function is giving as undefined.

```
describe('testStore', () => {
    // runs before each Test case.
    beforeEach( () => {  
       dispatcher = require('../../dispatcher').default;
    });  
    // Example test case
    it('test1', () => {
       expect(dispatcher.register.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

Comment: How do you mock it?

Comment: I am using jest-cli 21.x and React 0.14, I guess Dispatcher is thoroughly mocked by Jest automatically.

Comment: There is no automocking in jest anymore

Comment: @AndreasKöberle : Thanks man , I was not aware of it.